# Program to log which program has the focus on Microsoft Windows

Tags: windows, logs

I am looking for a program that can log which program has the focus on Microsoft Windows.

The program should run on Microsoft Windows. Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Window Focus Logger ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703234500/http://www.adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger/)) (original source broken: [www.adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger](http://www.adminscope.com/downloads/window-focus-logger))

- Microsoft Windows XP, 7, 8
- Portable
- Free for personal and commercial use
- Requires Microsoft .NET Framework 4

[image: screenshot of Window Focus Logger]

Answer (score 3):

You can use https://www.happydroid.com/focus  (also available via [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703234127/http://www.happydroid.com/focus)).

Features:

- Microsoft Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10
- Portable
- Gratis
- CLI

[image: screenshot of Focus]